# implementing radio buttons and check box in corona

Tags: radio-button, coronasdk

Can we have check box, radio button or any other buttons implementation in corona?If so ,how?I got a third party tool http://x-pressive.com/WidgetCandy_Corona/media.html  which has these features that implements the functionality ,but it is not free and cant be tested?Basically I want to create a Business application where I can use these features.Can anybody let me know how do I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think u can do it in corona. They have some widget API, you can find in the sample code > interface > widget demo. But check box not included.

I my apps, I build those check box by my own. I have to pay $20 for each image of those button or check box on stock image web.
In your case, If you want it looks good and you are not good at illustrator or photoshop, widgetCandy could be your best choice.

I paid for x-pressive's effectCandy and TextCandy. It worth the cost. This WidgetCandy is their new product, I don't have a chance to try it yet, but I would suggest you try it.

The downside is you have to learn some new API in order to use their function.